# Laptop RAM Details

Tags: laptop, memory

I have Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 Laptop which is running on 6GB RAM. Once i typed `sudo dmidecode --type 17` in the terminal i got the following output separated into 4 blocks.

So the questions are next:

1. Does it mean i have 4 slots for RAM?
2. Do I have 2 separated physical RAM modules installed (4096 MB and
   2048 MB respectively) ?
3. If I might want to upgrade my Laptop RAM in the future, which
   indicator should I be based on, so the purchase fits my laptop as
   much as possible?

.

```
\#dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 9670C708
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5273DH0-CH9  
    Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 94898C78
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5773DH0-CH9  
    Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
```

Comment: Please add a blank linke before your list. That way it will be displayed as one.

Answer (score 2):

1. It means the BIOS thinks there are 4 banks of memory, with two channels in total. It possible that the board doesn't actually have a way to connect a second bank to one channel, or that only a slightly different laptop model has that option.

   In doubt, what counts is what is on the board. So open the laptop up and look inside.
2. Yes. The DMI BIOS information is useful to see what you actually *have* installed (or what the BIOS thinks is actually installed).
3. The BIOS information is based on what you *have* installed. It doesn't say anything about what you *can* install (larger/faster RAM). For that, you need to consult the manual or the manufacturer. Of course, if, say, the RAM breaks, you are on the safe side if you replace it with a module based on the same specs.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure about how that command handles it. It's better to check your [manual](https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/z370_z470_z570_ug_en.pdf) or [maintenance manual](https://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User's%20guides%20and%20manuals/Z370&Z470&Z570/Lenovo%20Z370Z470Z570%20Hardware%20Maintenance%20Manual%20V1.0.pdf), it should have that information and also how to access he slots. So eventually you'd have to check it anyway. Both have instructions on how open the cover to access the slots and the maintenance manual states it's two slots (which is typical for a lot of Laptops).
2. Yes.
3. Refer to your manual. It should have all the information and probably even a supported module list. If it doesn't connect the manufacturer. Otherwise try to match the ones you have.

Comment: Here's what I found: https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/z370_z470_z570_ug_en.pdf. It's not pretty clear about my questions, so maybe you can help me. It says I can use DDR3 SDRAM supported by my computer, but no specific. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's missing that information. Either match your current modules or contact the manufacturer. Beware that those modules are different (smaller) than the normal RAM modules for PCs!